# How to manually set up a Chef node?

Tags: chef, knife, chef-server

I have a Chef server running on Ubuntu 14.04 (see *Note 1*) and I can access the "Chef Manage" website by visiting the IP address (`mychefserver.myorg.com`) in my browser.

I have a workstation running on Mac OS X El Capitan (see *Note 2*) and I can connect to the Chef server using `knife ssl check` and `knife client list`.

The problem: `knife` won't bootstrap my third machine (`mynode.myorg.com`) as a node.

```
$ knife bootstrap mynode.myorg.com --sudo --ssh-user myname --forward-agent --node-name mynode
Creating new client for mynode
Creating new node for mynode
Connecting to mynode
Failed to authenticate myname - trying password auth
Enter your password: stty: 'standard input': unable to perform all requested operations

ERROR: Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user myname@mynode@mynode
```

`mynode.myorg.com` is a corporate machine. SSH is set up to allow only certificate-based authentication. SSH with password and SSH with private key is disallowed.

It seems to me that since `knife bootstrap` uses password- or key-based SSH, and since I can reach a command line on the node by simply running `ssh mynode.myorg.com`, my best option is to SSH into the node and set Chef up manually. Unfortunately, there is no documentation for how to create a Chef node that doesn't involve invoking `knife bootstrap` from a workstation.

**What commands do I have to run locally on the node to recreate the work performed by** `knife bootstrap`**?**

---

*Note 1:* Chef Server 12.4.1 setup steps

```
$ wget https://packagecloud.io/chef/stable/packages/ubuntu/trusty/chef-server-core_12.4.1-1_amd64.deb/download
$ dpkg -i download
$ cat > /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb
server_name = 'mychefserver.myorg.com'
api_fqdn server_name
bookshelf['vip'] = server_name
nginx['url'] = "https://#{server_name}/"
nginx['server_name'] = server_name
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/#{server_name}.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/#{server_name}.key"
^D
$ chef-server-ctl reconfigure
$ chef-server-ctl install opscode-manage
$ chef-server-ctl reconfigure
$ opscode-manage-ctl reconfigure
$ chef-server-ctl install opscode-reporting
$ chef-server-ctl reconfigure
$ opscode-reporting-ctl reconfigure
$ chef-server-ctl user-create myname My Name myname@myorg.com mypassword --filename myname.pem
$ chef-server-ctl org-create myorg "My Org" --association_user myname
```

---

*Note 2:* ChefDK 0.11.2 workstation setup steps

```
$ wget URL: https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/mac_os_x/10.11/x86_64/chefdk-0.11.2-1.dmg
$ hdiutil mount chefdk-0.11.2-1.dmg
$ installer -package '/Volumes/Chef Development Kit/chefdk-0.11.2-1.pkg' -target '/Volumes/Macintosh HD'
$ hdiutil unmount '/Volumes/Chef Development Kit/'
$ chef generate app chef-repo
$ cd chef-repo
$ mkdir .chef
$ cat > .chef/myname.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
# …snip…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
^D
$ cat > .chef/knife.rb
log_level        :info
log_location     STDOUT
node_name        'myname'
client_key       "#{__dir__}/myname.pem"
chef_server_url  'https://mychefserver.myorg.com/organizations/myorg'
cookbook_path    ["#{__dir__}/../chef-repo/cookbooks"]
^D
$ knife ssl fetch
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### 1. Install chef-client

Either use the https://www.chef.io/chef/install.sh script or download and install the correct chef-client package for your OS.

#### 2. Create /etc/chef/client.rb

Perhaps you can use one of your bootstrapped nodes as a reference. The important bit is that you have `chef_server_url` pointing at your Chef server.

Example:

**`/etc/chef/client.rb`**

```
chef_server_url           "https://mychefserver.myorg.com/organizations/myorg"
validation_client_name    "myorg-validator"
validation_key            "/etc/chef/myorg-validator.pem"
log_level                 :info
```

#### 3. Copy validation key

The key you got after running `chef-server-ctl org-create`. If lost you can generate a new one from Chef Manage.

Copy the key to `/etc/chef/myorg-validator.pem` (to what is configured as `validation_key` in `client.rb`)

#### 4. Fetch SSL cert

Optionally, if the SSL certificate on your Chef server isn't signed (it probably isn't), you must manually fetch it so that knife/chef-client will trust the certificate.

```
mkdir /etc/chef/trusted_certs
knife ssl fetch -c /etc/chef/client.rb
```

See also http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2014/12/11/chef-12-fix-untrusted-self-sign-certs/

Comment: Take care, if you try a ssl fetch with your client.rb you will received this message : ERROR: ArgumentError: Cannot sign the request without a client name, check that :node_name is assigned

Comment: For windows client?